# Heroku - Transfer domain name befor deployment

Tags: heroku, domain-name

I have reserved a domain name with another hosting provider that I would like to transfer to Heroku before deploying my application. Indeed, the domain name transfer takes up to 2 weeks and I would like it to be transferred as soon as possible so that I can deploy my application on this domain name.
So, can I import my domain name without deploying my application?

Thanks.
Paul-Emile

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer"? And why are you expecting this to take two weeks? Heroku isn't a name registrar. You can use custom domains, but you'd register them elsewhere and just have to make DNS changes, which are generally much faster than that.

Comment: I'm confused by this request. Doesn't that mean you'll incur downtime between when the DNS changes occur and you first deploy your application? Normally I'd plan to deploy to a regular Heroku subdomain, make sure everything is working, _then_ set up DNS.